# Recursively plot multiple tables and outputs to images in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

Hi I have multiple tables, let say 20 tables, to be plotted and outputted to jpeg images as below.

table1:

```
list percentage  
1    20         
2    50   
3    30  
...
```

table2:

```
list percentage  
1    40         
2    10    
3    20
...
```

I wish to do a for loop to recursively plot each table and output to a jpeg image. I tried the code below:

```
for (i in 1:20) {
    jpeg(paste0("plot_",i,".jpg"))
    plot(paste0("table",i, "$percentage"))
    dev.off()
}
```

It showed error. I wonder how I can write to get it worked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with maybe 2 plots prepared so we can see what the error is. Right now, I don't see anything resembling a plot being sent to the jpeg. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi mysteRious, in my case, I would like to plot graph for 20 tables and output to 20 jpeg images by executing plot(table1$percentage), plot(table2$percentage), ... and so on in a loop. How could I get it worked? I will add more features to the plot but I wish to at least get the looping worked first.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a string to *plot* is probably what is causing you problems. Use *eval*:

```
for (i in 1:20) {
    jpeg(paste0("plot_",i,".jpg"))
    plot(eval(parse(text=paste0("table",i, "$percentage"))))
    dev.off()
}
```